# MySQL SELECT, store in a variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select, local-variables

For a stored procedure, I want to do a SELECT, and store a column's value into a variable.

How do I do this?

I want to do something like this:

```
    DECLARE countTemp INT;
    SET countTemp=(SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM mytable WHERE Name= var_name LIMIT 0,1);
```

OR, like this :

```
    DECLARE countTemp INT;
    SELECT countTemp=ColumnXYZ FROM mytable WHERE Name= var_name LIMIT 0,1;
```

But, I tried these and MySQL says my syntax is incorrect; how do I do something like this?

Comment: Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: `Script line: <#> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE countTemp INT;
SET countTemp=SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM myTa' at line <#>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :

```
DECLARE myvar nvarchar(50);

SELECT ATextColumn INTO myvar FROM myTable LIMIT 1,1;

SELECT CONCAT('myvar is ',myvar ,' .');
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Procedure-Function/UseselectintotoassignvaluetoanIntegervariable.htm

Comment: I guess you answered your own question ?

Comment: You have to wait two days before you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set the variable in the select query

```
SELECT @countTemp := ColumnXYZ FROM mytable WHERE Name= var_name LIMIT 0,1;
```

**@countTemp** is your variable!